# When is the earliest point you can learn Saria's Song?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

So, I just tried going to the Sacred Meadow directly after getting the Fairy Ocarina and Saria wasn't there. Do I absolutely have to talk to Darunia before she'll appear, and teach me Saria's Song, and then return to Darunia to play it for him?

Or does she appear, say, after meeting Zelda? Then you could play Saria's Song on your first meeting.

Comment: I believe you can do this straight after leaving the Castle. I might be wrong, but I can't verify this until I test this out tonight.

Comment: I've definitely had Saria's Song when meeting Darunia for the first time, so I'm guessing @Ben is correct about it being after the Castle sequence.

Comment: Can confirm Ben's comment too, IIRC Navy starts mentioning Saria as soon as you meet Zelda for the first time, hinting you in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe after you learn Zelda's lullaby and get transported out of the castle you are able to get Saria's song, although I was unable to find any proof of this on the wiki, this is coming straight from memory.

**Update 6/13/17:**

I finally got around to doing another playthrough of this game and I tried to get the song before going to the castle but was unsuccessful. I was successful in getting it immediately after talking to Impa about Death Mountain, so I think it's safe to say that that is indeed the earliest point you can learn it.